# Was the Joker’s scar story true?

Tags: dc, batman, nolan-batman-trilogy, the-dark-knight

In *The Dark Knight*, the Joker describes a scenario in which his father once came home, attacked his mother, and then brandished a knife at him, all the while repeating the line “Why so serious?”

Is this story true?

Comment: Very related, not quite a dupe: [What is the Joker's real name?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6209/what-is-the-jokers-real-name)

Comment: Rule #1 : The Joker lies.

Comment: It's a duplicate, but not on THIS site. There's an excellent answer here: http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/1428/what-is-the-real-reason-for-the-jokers-scars

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There's no clear answer as to how the Joker got his scars in The Dark Knight. In the movie he gives two stories.

1. His father gave it to him as a child.
2. He gave it to himself to cheer up his wife.

This is a reference to *Batman: The Killing Joke* where he sees his past as being multiple choice.