# What are the identities of the three Jokers in the DC universe?

Tags: dc, batman, dc-extended-universe

Recently I watched some Youtube channels I follow and one blew my mind: it said there are three different Jokers. Here’s [an example video about the 3 Jokers theory](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7fPcQ2DwxsE), but there are virtually a TON of em on Youtube now.

How is this possible? Well... comics, so duh!

But does Batman know this? Maybe, maybe not.

Anyway, my question is: who are these three guys?

Comment: http://www.techtimes.com/articles/160951/20160525/justice-league-50-finally-reveals-the-jokers-real-identity-sort-of.htm

Comment: [Who says they’re all guys?](http://nerdist.com/the-identity-of-marvels-female-thor-finally-revealed-spoilers/)

Comment: Whichever video you watched (a link would have been handy, to help us understand your question) might have been referring to the three different Joker origin stories presented in *The Killing Joke*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the Joker's real name?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6209/what-is-the-jokers-real-name)

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - This isn't a dupe. In the new continuity there are three distinct jokers, each with a different identity.

Comment: @Valorum: ah yes, I only read your link after doing the dupe thing. That’s *probably * what this super-vague question is referring to, he said, passive-aggressively.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - Let that be a lesson to you :-)

Comment: @Valorum: if the answer is bothering to read things, I reject the question.

Comment: Having that much mod power must be boring sometimes. It was clearly a question about 3 Jokers, not 1. So "mindblown" here as to how this can be a dupe.

Comment: Can you link the video so we can have some more context and try to figure what they're referring to? I've seen some articles mentioning the three actors who have portrayed the Joker in live-action movies.

Comment: @Cherubel: I was the one who thought it was a duplicate, and I’m not a mod. But your original question was pretty vague.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Spoilers Ahead for DC Universe Rebirth. You have been warned.**

> In the New 52, The Justice League are infused with such power that they transform into various Gods. Superman is the God of strength, Flash is the God of Death and Batman becomes the God of Knowledge, along with possession of the Mobius Chair, a device built by Metron to aid him on his quest for knowledge. This chair has a hell of a lot of information stored in its database.
> [image][image]
> [image]
>  Batman asks the chair what the Joker's name is, but it doesn't give him one. Instead, it informs him that there are in fact three Jokers running around. Each one seems to be a Joker from a different era of Batman, the original Joker, the 70s/80s Joker and the modern redesigned Snyder Joker.

Comment: “Flash is the God of Death”. [Well... obviously?](https://www.ap2hyc.com/2013/08/the-justice-league-as-the-greek-gods/)

Comment: He fuses with the Black Racer, the Avatar of Death, so...... yeah.